# How to visually represent time evolution in 2-d Brownian motion simulation

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have modeled Brownian motion in both the x and y directions as random walks. I have plotted the data on a 2-d plot but, while it is not so difficult to trace the simulated particle's path from the origin, I want to be able to see the time-evolution of the particle's path visually represented on the plot, whether it be by changing the color of the line over time, or by adding a third dimension to the plot to represent time, or by using some sort of dynamic graph type.

I haven't tried implementing anything, but I have tried to look at what options are available to me. I want to avoid using a 3d plot if possible. That said, I am open to using something other than matplotlib if it makes sense for this situation (like pyqtgraph).

Here is my code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#n is how many trajectory evaluations
n = 1000
t= np.linspace(0,10000,num=n)
def brownianMotion(time):
    B = [0]
    for t in range(len(time)-1):
        nrand = random.gauss(0,(time[t+1] - time[t])**.5)
        B.append(B[t]+nrand)
    return B
xpath = brownianMotion(t)
ypath = brownianMotion(t)

def plot(x,y):
    plt.figure()
    xplot = np.insert(x,0,0)
    yplot = np.insert(y,0,0)
    plt.plot(xplot,yplot,'go-',lw=1,ms=.1)
             #np.arange(0,n+1),'go-', lw=1, ms = .1)
    plt.xlim([-150,150])
    plt.ylim([-150,150])
    plt.title('Brownian Motion')
    plt.xlabel('xDisplacement')
    plt.ylabel('yDisplacement')
    plt.show()
plot(xpath,ypath)
```

All in all, this is just for fun and something I did while bored at work. All suggestions are welcome! Thank you for your time!

Please let me know if I should post a picture of my code's output.

Edit: Additionally, if I wanted to represent multiple particles in the same graph, how could I do that so that the multiple pathes are distinguishable? I have modified my code for this purpose shown below but currently this code outputs a messy green mixture of particles.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nparticles = 20
#n is how many trajectory evaluations
n = 100
t= np.linspace(0,1000,num=n)
def brownianMotion(time):
    B = [0]
    for t in range(len(time)-1):
        nrand = random.gauss(0,(time[t+1] - time[t])**.5)
        B.append(B[t]+nrand)
    return B
xs = []
ys = []
for i in range(nparticles):
    xs.append(brownianMotion(t))
    ys.append(brownianMotion(t))
#xpath = brownianMotion(t)
#ypath = brownianMotion(t)
def plot(x,y):
    plt.figure()
    for xpath, ypath in zip(x,y):
        xplot = np.insert(xpath,0,0)
        yplot = np.insert(ypath,0,0)
        plt.plot(xplot,yplot,'go-',lw=1,ms=.1)
             #np.arange(0,n+1),'go-', lw=1, ms = .1)
    plt.xlim([np.amin(x),np.amax(x)])
    plt.ylim([np.amin(y),np.amax(y)])
    plt.title('Brownian Motion')
    plt.xlabel('xDisplacement')
    plt.ylabel('yDisplacement')
    plt.show()
plot(xs,ys)
```